# My function returns empty. why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that this is a basic question but I am stuck with it somewhere in my code. I got that code from somewhere but now I am modifying it according to my need.

What does jQuery('#selector') do? In my code it always return empty.

Here is my code

```
query: function (selector, context) {
            var ret = {}, that = this, jqEls = "", i = 0;
            if(context && context.find) {
                jqEls = context.find(selector);
            } else {
                jqEls = jQuery(selector);
            }
            ret = jqEls.get();
            ret.length = jqEls.length;
            ret.query = function (sel) {
                return that.query(sel, jqEls);
            }

            return ret;
        }
```

when I call this query function then I pass selector as parameter. When I do `console.log(selector)` it does have all the selectors which I need in this function. But the problem is on this line `jqEls = jQuery(selector);`. when I do `console.log(jqEls)` after this it returns empty thus the whole function returns empty.

Can I use something different then this to make it work?

Comment: Its a lot of a code in several files. So how can I give it a demo with that much of a code? any suggestion? jsfiddle is not gonna be appropriate for this one.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/stZzR/.

Comment: You should read up on basic jQuery selectors. Here's the docs for the ID selector, which is what you're using: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/. Also, your function is doing almost exactly what the `jQuery` function already does, so what's the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jquery('#selector')` is the equivalent of `document.getElementById('selector')`. If there is no DOM node with an id of `selector`, you get an empty result.

e.g.

```
<div id="selector">...</div>
```

would return the dom node corresponding to this div. Do you have jquery loaded?

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery(selector)` is looking for a DOM element that meets the selector criteria.

```
$('#example') == jQuery('#example')
```

Both will look for something with id "example"

Answer (score 0):

After reading your code I have a question : do you put the # in your variable `selector` ?
A solution to solve this by replacing the bad line by `jqEls = jQuery("#" + selector);`

If the problem isn't due to that can you say the type of `selector` ? string ? object ? jQueryObject ?

Comment: Yes selector id prefixed with `#`. And can you elaborate your second question? I really do not get your last comment.

Comment: I just mean the return of `typeof selector`. Which version of jQuery are you using ? Do you use multiple versions of jQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

`$(selector).get()` will return `undefined` if no element is found. This is why your function returns `undefined`. To fix this, you could use a default value if there is no element found:

```
ret = jqEls.length ? jqEls.get() : {};
```

This way your function will always return an object that has your `length` and `query` properties, but it will not have an element if jQuery did not find one.

Comment: As it is mentioned in my post the problem is with this line `jqEls = jQuery(selector);`. After this line jqEls is empty so by default this line `ret = jqEls.get();` will return undefined.

Comment: @al0neevenings `jQuery(selector)` will ALWAYS return a jQuery object. if no elements were matched, `length` will be 0 and `.get()` will give you undefined. The code i posted deals with this by using an empty object `{}` instead of undefined if there was no element found.

Comment: But the selector I am passing is valid and there are HTML elements in my html code with IDs. Then why it does not match?

Comment: the most common reason a match fails is because you're searching for the element before it exists in the DOM. you'd need to post your HTML and the rest of your javascript for us to tell.